# Is there any function to convert value to number format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there function to convert a value to number format in JavaScript?

Ex: 10006.1056 to 10,006.16

Comment: You may want [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

Comment: If you're interested in a library that is a whole lot more powerful that what comes built-in, check out http://numeraljs.com/

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is.

Best way is to create a `NumberFormat` you can re-use for your locale.

For example 'en-US' (USA) or 'en-IN' (India).

To set the maximum precision digits, use the option `maximumFractionDigits`.
If you always want to use 2 precision digits for example: 1 must be 1.00 use `minimumFractionDigits` too.

```
var number = 10006.1056;
var nf = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    maximumFractionDigits:2, 
    minimumFractionDigits:2
});

var formattedNumber = nf.format(number); // Will output 10,006.10
```